# Re-acl from text file

Tags: powershell, import, file-get-contents, import-from-excel, icacls

This one is stumping me. I am trying to do this with PowerShell, but it does not have to be...

Basically, I have a text file containing ACLs information for a large directory structure that has been migrated (I realize there is much to be desired from the contents, but we no longer can access the original filesystem, so this is what we have to work with).

I need to generate a batch file to re-acl the new (copied) file system.

So in a nutshell, I need to convert text like this (sorry for the scroll, but I am trying to preserve the line spacing):

```
Path: \\Share.Domain.com\Directory01$\Subdirectory01


AccessToString : DOMAIN\Group01-Knuckleheads Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
     BUILTIN\Administrators 



Path: \\Share.Domain.com\Directory02$\Subdirectory01


AccessToString : DOMAIN\Different-Group02 Allow  FullControl
                 BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
```

Into new files (or the same files, doesn't matter really) with the content like this:

```
ICacls "\\Share.Domain.com\Directory01$\Subdirectory01" /Grant "DOMAIN\Group01-Knuckleheads":(OI)(CI)R,X,S /t /c /l /q /inheritance:r
ICacls "\\Share.Domain.com\Directory01$\Subdirectory01" /Grant "BUILTIN\Administrators":(OI)(CI)F /t /c /l /q /inheritance:r
ICacls "\\Share.Domain.com\Directory02$\Subdirectory01" /Grant "DOMAIN\Different-Group02":(OI)(CI)F /c /l /q /inheritance:r
ICacls "\\Share.Domain.com\Directory02$\Subdirectory01" /Grant "BUILTIN\Administrators":(OI)(CI)F /c /l /q /inheritance:r
```

My semi-pathetic attempt to work this out are still progressing, but I realize that this foe is greater than my mojo:

```
    #$ACLs = Get-Content C:\Scripts\Test\AndTest.txt
    #ForEach-Object ($ACL in $ACLs)
    #{
    #Figure out how to break strings into variables....
    #}
    #Declare Var - Need to populate from the imported text file
    $FilePath = "\\Share.Domain.com\Directory01$\Subdirectory01"
    $GroupName = "DOMAIN\Domain Admins"
    $TestPerm = "ReadAndExecute"
    If ($TestPerm = "FullControl"){$Perms = "F"}
    Elseif ($TestPerm = "ReadAndExecute"){$Perms = "RX"}
    Elseif ($TestPerm = "Modify"){$Perms = "M"}
    Elseif ($TestPerm = "Deny"){$Perms = "D"}
    Elseif ($TestPerm = "Read"){$Perms = "R"}
    Elseif ($TestPerm = "Write"){$Perms = "W"}
    cls
    #Build icacls string -Test Output
    Write-Host "ICacls ""$FilePath"" /Grant ""$GroupName"":(OI)(CI)$Perms /t /c /l /q /inheritance:r"
    #Write icacls batch file
    #Out-File "C:\Scripts\Test\re-acl.cmd" "ICacls ""$FilePath"" /Grant ""$GroupName"":(OI)(CI)$Perms /t /c /l /q /inheritance:r"
```

I realize that there is a bunch of work to do here & I am just starting to figure this out. For example, I am thinking I need to list the permissions into an array and build the string as such. There are also bound to be special permissions etc...

But for now, I am trying to figure out how to import the text file and then break it down into variables... Like I said, I am working in Powershell, but it really can be anything... VB or Python perhaps?

Big thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm thinking there might be an easier way to get this done. You can read the access rights set on a file using the GetAccessControls() methods. Try it out like this `(ls foo.txt).GetAccessControl()`. If you have access to both folders at the same time you might be able to transfer right easier that way. There's also a `SetAccessControl()` method to set them, thought I've never used it myself.

Comment: @n3wjack _but we no longer can access the original filesystem,_

Comment: Exactly... What happened was, we had some scripts that did this properly, and I was writing this little script to dump the acls in a human readable form... One of my coworkers asked to use it & I did not know they did not run the original... I only found out after cutover...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think most of your issue is parsing the text, so that's mainly what I helped with here. I did build the strings, and if you have more permissions that you want to include you should be able to figure out how to add them to the `switch`. For this we will want to read the entire text file in as a large multi-line string. Then we split it up into chunks based on the keyword "Path:". Then for each record I get the path out as a string, grab the permissions, and parse out accounts, allow/deny, and individual accesses. Then I convert the accesses to short versions accepted by icacls, and build the arguments out as a formatted string.

I output to the host, but once you are satisfied that it looks right to you, you can remove the `Write-Host "` and the trailing `"` and it will just execute it (assuming icacls is in the same folder that you're in, or in the PATH environment variable).

```
$Text = Get-Content C:\Scripts\Test\AndTest.txt -Raw
$Records = $Text -split "(?s)(Path:.*?)(?=Path:|$)"|?{$_}
#Loop through each file/ACL
ForEach($Record in $Records){
    $FilePath = ($Record -split "[\r\n]+")[0].Substring(6)
    $PermRecords = ($Record -split "(?s)AccessToString : "|Select -skip 1) -split "[\r\n]+"|?{$_}
    $Perms = $PermRecords|?{$_ -match "(.*\\.*?)\s+(Allow|Deny)(.*)$"}|%{[pscustomobject]@{'Account'=$Matches[1].Trim();'Type'=$Matches[2];'Perms'=$Matches[3].Trim()}}
    #Loop through each perm for the current file
    $Perms | %{
        #Convert friendly names to abbreviations
        $ShortPerms = ''
        Switch -regex ($_.Perms){
            "FullControl" {$ShortPerms = "F";Continue}
            "ReadAndExecute" {$ShortPerms += "RX,"}
            "Synchronize" {$ShortPerms += "S,"}
            "Modify" {$ShortPerms += "M,"}
            "Read(?=,|$)" {$ShortPerms += "R,"}
            "Write" {$ShortPerms += "W,"}
        }
        $ShortPerms = $ShortPerms.TrimEnd(',')
        $Arguments = '"{0}" /{4} "{1}":(OI)(CI)({2}) /t /c /l /q /inheritance:r' -f $FilePath, $_.Account, $ShortPerms,$(If($_.Type -eq 'Allow'){'Grant'}else{'Deny'})
        write-host "& ICAcls $Arguments"
    }
}
```

If the `-Raw` argument doesn't work for you, you can work around that with

```
(Get-Content C:\Scripts\Test\AndTest.txt) -join "`r`n"
```

Let me know if you have questions or issues.

Comment: Wow, you guys are so awesome. I really want to take my skill set to the next level and without these resources I would be totally lost if folks like you didn't answer the call.

Comment: When I ran this, I got the following error...
& ICAcls 
        Error formatting a string: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list..
        At line:21 char:146
        + ... e -eq 'Allow'){'Grant'}else{'Deny'})
        +                    ~~~~~~~
            + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: ("{0}" /{4} "{1}... /inheritance:r:String) [], RuntimeException
            + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatError

Comment: That $Arguments line variable `/{4}` should be `/{3}`. It's a zero based index and there are only 4 elements.
So:  `$Arguments = '"{0}" /{3} "{1}":(OI)(CI)({2}) /t /c /l /q /inheritance:r' -f $FilePath, $_.Account, $ShortPerms,$(If($_.Type -eq 'Allow'){'Grant'}else{'Deny'})`

Comment: Awesome! The last error I got is similar...   Exception calling "Substring" with "1" argument(s): "startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
Parameter name: startIndex"
At line:6 char:5
+     $FilePath = ($Record -split "[\r\n]+")[0].Substring(6)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: How do you guys do it... I mean, I code until I cry tears of blood and nothing works, or if it does, I am even more surprised... Then you guys come along and 10 minutes, it does the expected AND washes your car... Too bad that whole rockstar thing didn't work out for me back in highschool..